# Which is the most efficient and secure way for implementing an admin panel for a website?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, panel, admin

I am developing a website in ASP.NET, C# and SQL Server 2008. My colleagues suggest that I should build an admin panel as one of the **secured section of my website in one of my hosting server's directories** that is password locked. But what I think it will be more secure if I built it **as an application on my desktop PC** that don't have access to any outsider by using any scripting language like JavaScript and all. But I am not able to predict what is more efficient and secure way. First one or the second one. Please tell.

Answer (score 1):

Logically, the most efficient way has to be to extend the web app to include an admin area. That means you only have one application to maintain. Equally, if you were to build a desktop application, it will have to communicate with the web application, and presumably authenticate itself using, what..? A password, of course. So either way, you need to build a password protected area in the web site.

Comment: No I mean if database of the website is password protected and the application can access the database server only to operate on the data and it has nothing to do with the website part(the actual website code part,binaries,htmls and all). Then what do you think will be good?

Comment: also if suppose application is maintained by some other trusted person. I want to know what is best for performance, the desktop admin panel or web admin panel???